# Should status-declined (moderator-only tags) be allowed as the "Top tag"?

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, meta

I came to Meta Stack Exchange today to find something a bit... disheartening:

[image: Top tag... status-declined?]

It may be discouraging to users if their top tag on Meta is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Should this be allowed?

Comment: If I want to have something status-declined I know who to ask ... ;)

Comment: Imagine what it must be like fo that poor sap who has the [gold status-declined badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/294/status-declined)!

Comment: Did you tag this as [tag:discussion] instead of [tag:feature-request] so it wouldn't get [tag:status-declined]? :p

Comment: @JonEricson Yikes!! Earning a gold badge in that tag would reveal a very significant problem!!

Comment: @Namaste Not necessarily. In that user's case, they simply add status-declined to questions and then answer them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It may be disheartening; it can also be an *encouragement* to write a better received post.

Which you just did; <s>tomorrow, one of the tags on this question will probably be your top tag.</s> It turns out it doesn't, since the question scores are irrelevant. Only answers will help (and maybe *more* questions in a tag).

I personally would appreciate such a unique situation and [immediately save it to the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/save/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/474678/jl2210?tab=topactivity). Just like [this question by a ♦ moderator with a New Contributor indicator](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/239865/67785).

Comment: That moderator with the new contributor indicator is very strange... I've [asked about it](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3204/why-is-a-moderator-whose-been-around-for-8-years-a-new-contributor) on Meta.DBA.

Comment: @Glorfindel My top tag is *still* [meta-tag:status-declined]. What to do now?

Comment: I'm sorry ... Write a positively scoring answer, that will certainly help.

Comment: My new "Top Tag" is... [meta-tag:meta]. How appropriate.

Comment: That is *so* meta :)